# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' or return None at best

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm looking to get the url of one of the books: https://www.bookdepository.com/search?searchTerm=painted+house+grisham&search=Find+book

I'm trying to adapt the below code from a script I wrote for another site but it throws me the error in the title.

I don't know what part of the code is to be amended below. 
At best, this script returns `None` which tells me the `soup` turned flavorless. Thanks for your help.

```
def get_detail_data(soup):
"""Get info from each product page."""

    # title
    if extension == 'com':
        if site == 'bookdepository':
            try:
                title = soup.select_one('h1[itemprop="name"]')
                # for div in title.select('div'):
                #     div.extract()
                # title = title.get_text(strip=True).replace(';', ' ')
            except:
                title = ''
# ...code continues

def get_index_data(soup):
"""Get product link from index page (not pagination link)."""

    if extension == 'com':
        try:
            # links = soup.find_all('a', class_='s-item__link')
            # links = soup.find_all('h3', class_='title')
            # links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)[0]['href']
            links = soup.find("a").get("href")
            # links = soup.find_all('a', class_='s-item__link')
            # print(links)
            # links = soup.select('.title a')
            # for a in links:
            #     links = links.get_text(strip=True).replace(';', ' ')
        except:
            links = []

    elif #...code continues

    res_url = [item.get('href') for item in links]

    return res_url
```

==== UPDATE

In `get_index_data(soup)` I replaced `links = soup.find("a").get("href")` with `links = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'item-info'}).find_all("a", href=True)` to no avail.

Now when I hover over `links` in `res_url`, it tells me: `Local variable 'links' might be referenced before assignment`

I don't know where to go from there.

==== UPDATE

After a bit of cleaning, I'm now back to the same error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'` at the level of the `res_url` assignment. The `links` keyword is highlighted.

==== UPDATE

I used a string to define the url as `url = ''`. But now I moved on to a dictionary of urls as in `urls = {'url1': 'blah', 'url2': 'blah'}`

So the question now is how to convert `urls = [item.get('href') for item in links]` without `.get` to retrieve the url choosen by the user.

==== UPDATE

In `def get_index_data(soup)`, I came up with this line:
`links = [k for k, v in urls.items() if v == urls[site]]`

`urls` in `urls.items()` gets highlighted.

But my urls dictionary is located in the main() function at the bottom of the script. I put it at the top of the script. Nothing changes. 
So I don't how I can retrieve one url from the urls dictionary by using the `links` list comprehension above.

Comment: if you can give what is the data present in the soup or the whole code which computes soup we or anybody can help..

Comment: `links = soup.find("a").get("href")` is already calling the `get` method, which presumably returns a list of strings, so you can't call the `get` method on it again.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm trying to apply all your good advice and guidance. I'll report back asap. By the way, I updated the code. I cannot post everything unfortunately.

Comment: Just edited on my issue.

Comment: In some part of your if statement you are not defining links.

Comment: That's what I thought but isn't `links = ...` in my if statement supposed to define `links`? For sure, if the machine reacts like this, there must be a reason.

Comment: Is links defined in all branches of you if statement though? It's hard to guess without seeing all the code.

Comment: I only have two ifs here for `.com` and two for `.es`. That makes four `Links` assignments present as they are supposed to be.

Comment: I think I pinpointed the issue. Please see update for any thought you may have. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When your `try` fails, it will give you `links = []`. Then you try to iterate through an empty list, hence you get None. You also need to probably use `find_all()`, as `find()` will only return the first element it finds (in this case `a`, and if the `a` tag doesn't have an `href`, again you get back nothing.

You are going to have to do a bit of filtering, as there are 262 hrefs within the page source. I can help start you off with this, but you'll need to provide more details/info for more help:

Take a look at this code to help sort out what you want:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.bookdepository.com/search?searchTerm=painted+house+grisham&search=Find+book'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all("a", href=True)
for each in links:
    print(each.get('href'))
```

Comment: This works for sure but I edited my issue with more info you needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have beautiful soup 4.7.1 or above you can use following css selector to get all the product links.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url='https://www.bookdepository.com/search?searchTerm=painted+house+grisham&search=Find+book'
res=requests.get(url).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(res,'html.parser')
links=[item['href'] for item in soup.select("div.item-info >h3 >a[href]")]
print(links)
print(len(links))
```

**Output**:

```
['/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780440237228?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-1', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780099537021?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-2', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780385337939?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-3', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780345532046?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-4', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780385501200?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-5', '/La-granja-Painted-House-John-Grisham/9788499080826?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-6', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9781613834909?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-7', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780099416159?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-8', '/X100-Corks-Painted-House-Pallet-John-Grisham/9780099440895?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-9', '/Painted-House-Header-W-H-Smith-Only-John-Grisham/9780099442790?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-10', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780553527728?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-11', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780385501217?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-12', '/Painted-House-27c-Hc-Aud-LP-Mix-Flr-John-Grisham/9780385502399?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-13', '/Painted-House-12-Copy-Slimline-Floor-Display-John-Grisham/9780385501910?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-14', '/18c-MM-Solo-Flr-Display-Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780440803812?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-15', '/X18-Painted-House-Dumpbin-John-Grisham/9780712689618?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-16', '/RC-527-Painted-House-X6-Counterp-John-Grisham/9781856865081?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-17', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9781439568279?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-18', '/La-Casa-Dipinta-Painted-House-John-Grisham/9788804505518?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-19', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780099586098?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-20', '/Painted-House-Complete-Unabridged-John-Grisham/9780754054634?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-21', '/Die-Farm-5-Audio-CDs-Painted-House-5-Audio-CDs-dtsch-Version-John-Grisham/9783898308144?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-22', '/Brethren-John-Grisham/9780091896492?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-23', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780553712742?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-24', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780440295983?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-25', '/18c-Solo-Painted-House-TV-Tie-Floor-Display-with-Riser-John-Grisham/9780440805311?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-26', '/19-Copy-John-Grisham-Prepack-Incl-2-Tr-EA-Brethren-Chamber-King-Torts-Painted-House-Partner-Street-Lawyer-Rainmaker-John-Grisham/9780385395939?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-27', '/X18-Painted-House-Dumpbin-Export-John-Grisham/9780712689700?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-28', '/Painted-House-Complete-Unabridged-John-Grisham/9780754007272?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-29', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780736689434?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-30']
30
```

---

Or if you want to use find_all() for header class and then search find_next('a')

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url='https://www.bookdepository.com/search?searchTerm=painted+house+grisham&search=Find+book'
res=requests.get(url).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(res,'html.parser')
linksall=[item.find_next('a',href=True)['href'] for item in soup.find_all("div", class_="item-info")]
print(linksall)
print(len(linksall))
```

**Output**:

```
['/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780440237228?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-1', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780099537021?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-2', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780385337939?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-3', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780345532046?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-4', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780385501200?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-5', '/La-granja-Painted-House-John-Grisham/9788499080826?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-6', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9781613834909?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-7', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780099416159?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-8', '/X100-Corks-Painted-House-Pallet-John-Grisham/9780099440895?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-9', '/Painted-House-Header-W-H-Smith-Only-John-Grisham/9780099442790?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-10', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780553527728?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-11', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780385501217?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-12', '/Painted-House-27c-Hc-Aud-LP-Mix-Flr-John-Grisham/9780385502399?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-13', '/Painted-House-12-Copy-Slimline-Floor-Display-John-Grisham/9780385501910?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-14', '/18c-MM-Solo-Flr-Display-Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780440803812?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-15', '/X18-Painted-House-Dumpbin-John-Grisham/9780712689618?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-16', '/RC-527-Painted-House-X6-Counterp-John-Grisham/9781856865081?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-17', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9781439568279?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-18', '/La-Casa-Dipinta-Painted-House-John-Grisham/9788804505518?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-19', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780099586098?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-20', '/Painted-House-Complete-Unabridged-John-Grisham/9780754054634?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-21', '/Die-Farm-5-Audio-CDs-Painted-House-5-Audio-CDs-dtsch-Version-John-Grisham/9783898308144?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-22', '/Brethren-John-Grisham/9780091896492?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-23', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780553712742?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-24', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780440295983?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-25', '/18c-Solo-Painted-House-TV-Tie-Floor-Display-with-Riser-John-Grisham/9780440805311?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-26', '/19-Copy-John-Grisham-Prepack-Incl-2-Tr-EA-Brethren-Chamber-King-Torts-Painted-House-Partner-Street-Lawyer-Rainmaker-John-Grisham/9780385395939?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-27', '/X18-Painted-House-Dumpbin-Export-John-Grisham/9780712689700?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-28', '/Painted-House-Complete-Unabridged-John-Grisham/9780754007272?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-29', '/Painted-House-John-Grisham/9780736689434?ref=grid-view&qid=1579799743707&sr=1-30']
30
```

Hope this is what you after.

Comment: Thanks KunduK. But I will try your solutions as soon as I get the `links` assignment issue that I'm stuck with at the moment.